# Unit test results not showing in Sonar when building child projects in Jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have some maven projects configured in Jenkins, and I execute them from a parent project (which have them as `<modules`> in its pom.xml, the children have this project defined as `<parent`>).

The unit tests execute successfully for each project in Jenkins and it shows the results, but then in Sonar all projects appear as having no unit tests.

The sonar configuration for each project is

```
sonar.projectKey=project:key
sonar.projectName=project_name
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sources=src/main/java
tests=src/test/java
binaries=target/classes
```

Do I have to do anything else in order for Sonar to pick up the results of the unit tests being executed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see, I guess you're trying to run Sonar analyses with the Sonar Jenkins plugin "on-the-fly" mode, where you specify properties.

You have to understand that this mode does not support running tests: it can only reuse test reports (if you specify "sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports").

But as you are using Maven, why don't you just run the Sonar post-build action? (see [documentation for that](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Activate+Sonar+on+Jenkins+job))

Comment: Thank you very much Fabrice!

I switched to the post-build action (I don't know how I missed it before) and now everything is working perfectly.

(I had to switch the default unit test coverage tool from cobertura to jacoco because my project is using Java 7 and I haven't still updated to Sonar 3.2)